# json is not being received by php

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have an Ajax call:

```
            let jFormData = JSON.stringify(formData);
            //  {"list":["17810","17811","17812"],"chosen":"17812"}
            $('#json').val(jFormData);
            $.ajax({
                     url         : 'db_ajax/regDupAjax.php', 
                     type        : 'POST',
                     data        : jFormData, // our data object
                     dataType    : 'json',
                 })
```

The JSON has been validated. 
It is being sent to a php script and being read by

```
$json = $_POST['jFormData'];
```

but $json is an empty string.

What have I overlooked? I have tried dataType text, and have reviewed all the suggested similar questions without success.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` it probably does not exist in `$_POST['jFormData']`

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `data` in ajax request wait for object. If you want pass json string to `jFormData` key in $_POST you must pass it as new object:

```
            $.ajax({
                     url         : 'db_ajax/regDupAjax.php', 
                     type        : 'POST',
                     data        : { jFormData: jFormData }, // our data object
                     dataType    : 'json',
                 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the browser's developer console, you can track ajax post from the network section and check the sent values. You will be sure whether the values are sent correctly or if the post operation is successful.